# LINQ Contains Syntax issue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the .Contains here:

```
listIsSame = personalization.Options.Contains(item.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**Error:** Error 3 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid arguments C:\www\bug4443\Controls\ItemsContent.ascx.cs

obviously I don't understand how the syntax needs to be here.  I've tried several things with no luck.  I see that Contains is a generic method so...

Answer (score 5):

The [String.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) has this signature:

```
public bool Contains(string value)
```

There is no overload that takes a StringComparison parameter.

The only Contains method with two arguments the C# compiler finds is Queryable.Contains. But for this method, the types of the arguments do not match. Hence the error message.

You can use the [String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) instead:

```
listIsSame = personalization.Options.IndexOf(item.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

I'm not sure if this is recognized by LINQ-to-SQL though, if you happen to deal with an LINQ-to-SQL queryable.

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition or your personalization.Options object?

Linq's `contains` does contain the signature that you are using, however the error message is indicating that the object you are calling Contains from is not an `IQueryable`.